# Skorokhod representation for functions of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_n, X$ be random variables in a Polish space $E$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a set of continuous functions $F : E \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(X_n) \to F(X)$ in distribution for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$. Does it follow that there exists a joint probability space and random variables $Y_n, Y$ defined on it such that $Y_n = X_n$ in distribution for all $n$, $Y = X$ in distribution and $F(Y_n) \to F(Y)$ almost surely for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$?

Note that if we apply the usual Skorokhod representation theorem individually for each $F$, we will get such random variables $Y_n$ and $Y$ that dependent on $F$. What I need here are random variables $Y_n$ and $Y$ that are "universal" for the whole collection $\mathcal{F}$. Do we need an additional condition on $\mathcal{F}$ for the result to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a counterexample for $E=\mathbb R^2$, $X_n=(G,-G)$, $X=(G,G)$ for $G$ a standard gaussian variable, and $\mathcal F=\{F_1:(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1,F_2:(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_2\}$.

Indeed, if $Y_n=(Y^n_1,Y^n_2)$ equals $X_n$ in distribution, then $Y^n_1=-Y^n_2$ a.s. And if $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ equals $X$ in distribution, then $Y_1=Y_2$ a.s. But in that case, if you had almost surely, as $n$ goes to infinity, $F_1(Y_n)=Y^n_1\to F_1(Y)=Y_1$ and $F_2(Y_n)=-Y^n_1\to F_2(Y)=Y_1$ almost surely, then $Y_1=-Y_1$ a.s., which is not as $Y_1$ is a standard gaussian variable.